# Why websocket connection closes immediately...?

Tags: android, autobahn, autobahnws

When  i tried to create a websocket connection in android for implementing wamp using [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/android/), the connection is created and closed immediatley.

why this happening ....? 
 How to solve..........?

Part of my code is given below

```
private void start() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String wsuri = "ws://192.168.0.102:8080/ws";
    if (!connection.isConnected()) {
        Log.d("tag", "Not Connected");

    }
    connection.connect(wsuri, new ConnectionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("tag", "Connected to " + wsuri);
            testPubSub();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("tag", "disconnected");


        }

    });
}

protected void testPubSub() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    connection.subscribe(TOPIC, String.class, new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(String topicUri, Object event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("tag", "Event Recieved");
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for not posting the manifest file earlier. Its given below..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.testwamp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: please, post your manifest file

Comment: "why this happening ....?" You haven't posted the logcat so how can we answer you?

Comment: Does the websocket handshake happen successfully? You can check this by checking the request headers, and you should get Connection: upgrade and a 101 switching protocol. If the handshake is fine, check if your network has a firewall. This should help in debugging the issue.

Comment: This answer helped me address a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211037/wildfly-websocket-apache-websocket-is-already-in-closing-or-closed-state/#37785464

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't put [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```