# Java Websocket closes immediately

Tags: java, exception, websocket, client

I am trying to use TooTallNate's Java-Websocket to connect to OkCoin. I found this simple code example somewhere, but I can't get it to work. The connection is immediately closed and so the call `mWs.send(...)` throws a `WebsocketNotConnectedException`. I can't figure out why; so far I have found a number of similar questions, none of which have an answer.

```
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("wss://real.okcoin.cn:10440/websocket/okcoinapi");

            final WebSocketClient mWs = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String message) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshake) {
                    System.out.println("opened connection");
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
                    System.out.println("closed connection");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

            mWs.connect();

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("event", "addChannel");
            obj.put("channel", "ok_btccny_ticker");           

            mWs.send(obj.toString());

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println("URI not formatted correctly");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of the callbacks gets called?

Comment: only onClose() gets called

Comment: Does the websocket handshake happen successfully? You can check this by checking the request headers, and you should get Connection: upgrade and a 101 switching protocol. If the handshake is fine, check if your network has a firewall. This should help in debugging the issue.

Comment: This answer helped me address a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211037/wildfly-websocket-apache-websocket-is-already-in-closing-or-closed-state/#37785464

Answer (score 0):

Use `mWs.connectBlocking()` instead of `mWs.connect()` with this it will not close automatically.

[See](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket/1.3.4/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.html#connectBlocking--)