# Websocket connection opens and closes immediately

Tags: nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using websockets and have managed to successfully set up my war file on the AWS Beanstalk. I am using Nginx as a proxy server and a classic Load Balancer listening on port 80, and the protocol is TCP instead of HTTP. Cross-zone load balancing is enabled and Connection draining is also enabled with the draining timeout as 60 seconds. The logs aren't showing any errors.

I have not changed the default nginx.conf file.

The connection upgrade is happening successfully, with the status code returning '101 Switching Protocol'. I just cannot seem to figure out why the connection is closing immediately.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Attaching the image where the websocket connects and disconnects immediately]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wonderful answer [helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211037/wildfly-websocket-apache-websocket-is-already-in-closing-or-closed-state/#37785464) solve this problem.

It turns out that the corporate WiFi connection that I was on had a firewall which was immediately terminating my WebSocket connection. It worked perfectly fine when I tried on a different WiFi network that did not have any firewall configured.